# Google products are excessively slow

Tags: windows-server-2008, g-suite

We're running Windows 2000 for our office server. For years now we have had the problem where everything Google takes an excessively long time to do anything. Gmail hangs, Analytics takes forever, Google docs times out.

I have been back and forth with our ISP on this matter and they are convinced it has something to do with our server.

This does not happen when I am at home so the problem either lays with our server or with the ISP.

Here is a screencast to show you what I mean.
http://www.screencast.com/users/jamesvanderhoven/folders/Jing/media/f7ffce9a-0250-4112-b79d-7dc58c2c8b0a

Has anyone else experienced this kind of problem and is there a way to resolve this please?

This one's still not resolved. We have now replaced the server, upgraded to Windows 2008 and still the problem persists. The only thing I can think of is that it's something on our router or there is fault with our ISP.

I'd appreciate anyone else's input on this please. Thanks

Comment: While 2000 had performance problems I don't see how that would be related to this issue. All the same, you should give some thought to upgrading to something a bit more modern than a decade+ old OS, not least of all for security.

Comment: Hi John. We have recently upgraded to Server 2008 and all new hardware and Google is still super slow in South Africa. Here are my latest namebench results and I was wondering if you could make suggestions to improve this please? http://namebench.appspot.com/id/4577123

Answer (score 3):

First thought is what's your network set-up?  Where do client machines go for their DNS and how is internet traffic routed?  Are you routing via that server or do machines route out directly by some other gateway device?

Do have any kind of proxy or caching going on?

Can you try out some basic connectivity tests such as nslookup/ping/traceroute against some of the hosts that you're struggling with?

Edit:

I've had this issue before with a different site over a few months.  Turned out that it was the ISP had some kind of caching proxy in place that for some reason caused the same kind of huge slowdown on a single site.  After enough of us complaining the problem mysteriously cleared with no explanation from the ISP.

Comment: Hi Chris. I am not too much of a Server administrator, so if you can tell me what I need to look out for in terms of proxy and caching, I can check that and get back to you? Thanks

Comment: First off - how do your clients connect to the internet.  Do they have the IP address of your gateway router/firewall?  Or are they set to use the IP of the server (or another machine on the LAN) as their gateway?  In the browser have you got any settings entered for a proxy in the connection settings (depends on browser choice as to exactly where this is configured).

Comment: Hi Chris. We are running Windows Server 2008 (a brand new server bought just the other day). All our machines are connected to this server and the server is connected to the outside world. I also have no proxy settings set in the browser (I use multiple) to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like slow DNS to me - you could also use namebench (http://code.google.com/p/namebench/) to test DNS speed.

Also Chrome has a built in debugger you can use to narrow down the source of the problem - right click -> Inspect Element -> Timeline and then perform the same actions to get a break down of what is taking the time.

Comment: Hi James. Thanks for this. How would I namebench to test for a slow DNS?

Comment: The default test in name bench tests a score of servers including your locally (system) configured server and gives mean response times as well as a host of other statistics on who they've performed - this should be sufficient to see if DNS is worth investigating any further.

Comment: Thanks James is it safe to post those namebench results here as I see the results talk about "Vulnerable to poisoning attacks (poor port diversity)" and I don't want to put this up there if this is the case?

Comment: Is the vulnerable server yours or your ISPs? If it's on your network and not externally accessible then there shouldn't be any risk, if it's your ISPs server then it's public information anyway so posting it here doesn't give anyone information they couldn't find themselves (edit: you might like to append the output to the original question).

Comment: Hi James, hopefully this does not put us in harms way as I notice our IP address is X'd out. Could you take a look at this for me and suggest what we might do to remedy this Google issue as these come up a hell of a lot. Thanks. http://namebench.appspot.com/id/4197007

Comment: Your DNS looks fine from those results - your internal server seems to be caching properly and giving you fast results. I'd suggest pursuing the suggestions by @Chris W - ie, do you have a proxy server?

Comment: So we have tried namebench and made all the changes suggested and still, we are experiencing this problem. Google products run perfectly well in the early morning and late evenings but during the day, it comes a grinding halt where I cannot work at all. This leads me to believe that the problem MUST surely be with our ISP? Is there anything someone can suggest I send onto the ISP to try please?

Comment: How is connectivity to other sites when Google products are slow?